# Terraform 0.12: Output list of buckets, use as input for another module and iterate

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using Tf 0.12.  I have an s3 module that outputs a list of buckets, that I would like to use as an input for a cloudfront module that I've got.

The problem I'm facing is that when I do `terraform plan/apply` I get the following error `count.index is 0 |var.redirect-buckets is tuple with 1 element`

I've tried all kinds of splats moving the count.index call around to no avail.  My sample code is below.

```
module.s3

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "redirect" {
  count = length(var.redirects)

  bucket = element(var.redirects, count.index)
}
```

```
mdoule.s3.output
output "redirect-buckets" {
  value = [aws_s3_bucket.redirect.*]
}
```

```
module.cdn.variables
...
variable "redirect-buckets" {
  description = "Redirect buckets"
  default = []
}
....
```

The error is thrown down here

```
module.cdn

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "redirect" {
  count = length(var.redirect-buckets)

  default_cache_behavior {
    // Line below throws the error, one amongst many
    target_origin_id = "cloudfront-distribution-origin-${var.redirect-buckets[count.index]}.s3.amazonaws.com"
....
    //Another error throwing line
    target_origin_id = "cloudfront-distribution-origin-${var.redirect-buckets[count.index]}.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you look at the output from the s3 module what do you see? Could you edit that into the question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

module.s3

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "redirects" {
  for_each = var.redirects

  bucket = each.value
}
```

Your variable definition for **redirects** needs to change to something like this:

```
variable "redirects" {
  type = map(string)
}
```

module.s3.output:

```
output "redirect_buckets" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.redirects
}
```

module.cdn

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "redirects" {
  for_each = var.redirect_buckets

  default_cache_behavior {
    target_origin_id = "cloudfront-distribution-origin-${each.value.id}.s3.amazonaws.com"
}
```

Your variable definition for **redirect-buckets** needs to change to something like this (note underscores, using skewercase is going to behave strangely in some cases, not worth it):

```
variable "redirect_buckets" {
  type = map(object(
    {
      id = string
    }
  ))
}
```

root module

```
module "s3" {
  source = "../s3" // or whatever the path is
  redirects = {
    site1 = "some-bucket-name"
    site2 = "some-other-bucket"
  }
}

module "cdn" {
  source = "../cdn" // or whatever the path is
  redirects_buckets = module.s3.redirect_buckets
}
```

From an example perspective, this is interesting, but you don't need to use outputs from S3 here since you could just hand the cdn module the same map of redirects and use for_each on those.

There is a tool called Terragrunt which wraps Terraform and supports dependencies.

https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/execute-terraform-commands-on-multiple-modules-at-once/#dependencies-between-modules

Comment: thanks for the tips.  I wasn't aware of the different and/or newer ways to express things in Terraform.  Especially that `map` declaration for my input variable.  I think it helps readability a lot, without leaking too much of what's being passed around.

Comment: I am glad it helped you. I would usually use for loops or splat indexing to make the output just the names of the buckets or their ARNs to leak even less. It does get a bit tangly though and makes the example more complicated.